# Star Rating in Lightning Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a API as follows:
"practitionerReviewSummary": {
"avg_overall_rating": 4.15,
"total_reviews": 4
}
In the UI , I will show 5 stars(asterisk) and if avg_overall_rating = 4 then I will make bold 4 stars.
But in the api avg_overall_rating = 4.15 then how do I show in the UI.
I do not have a specific code to show because I did not understand.Does any body know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to play around with partially filling your stars I would suggest the following approach:

Do Math.round on your rating => If rating >= 4.5 then it'll display 5 and it is 4 <= 4 <4.5 it'll display 4

Comment: Thank you, I am not doing partial filling of stars.That would be a big effort. so I am doing Math.round and this resolves my issue.

Comment: cool, please mark my answer as a solution, so this question is closed

Comment: I think I have marked your answer as a solution.

Comment: no problem happens. Thanks